# How to design a React component similar to WHO Coronavirus Disease (COVID-19) Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, user-experience, react-component

I want to design a map component similar to

> WHO Coronavirus Disease (COVID-19) Dashboard map component. for a particular country, where different regions can be selected based on a prop.

[WHO Coronavirus Disease (COVID-19) Dashboard](https://covid19.who.int/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIp_mXhfrQ6gIVBQ4rCh3ZuwzOEAAYASAAEgIYW_D_BwE)

[image]

> any references or guidance would be much helpful. I have no clue to do it. don't downvote it

Comment: Please provide more info. What have you tried so far? Sample code?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need a Chart library like https://d3js.org/ to be enable to plot the graphs. I found D3js to be the most flexible amongst all the libraries.

Then you can integrate the data from your database to the plotting methods provided with the library

**Examples of D3js plots:**

1. https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-map
2. https://observablehq.com/@d3/spike-map

**Other Plotting libraries**

1. Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery
2. Highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps
3. JS charting:https://jscharting.com/examples/chart-types/geographic-map/
4. Plotly: https://plotly.com/javascript/